# How to run profiling on the unit test target in the xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have one test case which I use for performance test in the test target, so I want to use the Profile instrument to see the Allocations, but I see menu the profile can't be executed, did I have the method to profile my unit test target.

Comment: What unit test framework are you using?  XCTest?